# How to give path in create_proc_entry function?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, kernel

how to mention the path in third argument of create_proc_entry() function. Till now i keep NULL over there, it is working fine but i want to keep under /proc/net/ directory for that i need to mention something over third argument.Let me give the instructions to do so

Comment: This question already has been answered, but the answers were not proper. please specify if have any suggestions. tq U

Answer (score 0):

struct proc_dir_entry *create_proc_entry(const char *name, mode_t mode,
                                         struct proc_dir_entry *parent);

```
proc_entry = create_proc_entry("megharaj_proc", 0666, path/NULL);
```

Comment: what is path?. and what we need to keep in path?

Comment: proc_entry = create_proc_entry("megharaj_proc", 0666, NULL); if NULL is used will be present in the home folder /proc. If you want it to be inside any folder of the proc use /proc/folder_name  instead of NULL

Comment: but that is not a char * type. it is type of struct proc_dir_entry *parent then how can we pass path

Comment: it is. See the struct proc_dir_entry

Comment: I have seen the struct proc_dir_entry in proc_fs.h file. But i didn't get any way to pass path. mention the code if you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter is a pointer to the "parent", not a path.
You can simply create a directory under /proc by calling:

```
proc_dir_entry *parent = NULL;
parent = proc_mkdir("your_parent_name",NULL);
```

Then use that pointer as your parent when creating your desired proc entry that
will appear under /proc/your_parent_name/my_proc as follows:

```
proc_dir_entry *my_proc = NULL
my_proc = create_proc_entry("my_proc", 0666, parent);
```

Comment: I don't want to create new directory. I want to keep an entry under already existed directory e.g like /proc/net/myEntry. I tried with proc_mkdir(), it created a new directory, i lost my old entry too